# What was Jadzia's original last name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Trills have a first name and a family name. A joined Trill replaces their family name with the symbiont's name. Thus Ezri Tigan became Ezri Dax when she was unwillingly joined.

It recently occurred to me that I don't know Jadzia's family name.  There doesn't seem to be any information on Memory Alpha. I suppose it was never stated onscreen.

Are there any novels/comics/other that have given a name for her?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't mentioned in the show. Moving down the canon scale to the books, we learn that her family name is ***Idaris***.

> A slender shadow, taller than any of the spires, fell across a grave marker bearing a name that was barely discernible in the waning light: JADZIA IDARIS
>
> <sub><sup>[Worlds of Deep Space Nine: Volume II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Worlds_of_Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine,_Volume_Two)</sup></sub>

and

> He’d known Dax for more than thirty years, through three permanent hosts: Curzon Antrani, **Jadzia Idaris**, and Ezri Tigan. All of them had surprised him many times during their friendships, but perhaps none more so than Ezri
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: Typhon Pact 09 - The Fall: Revelation and Dust](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Revelation_and_Dust)</sup></sub>

Comment: For the record, the ST Encyclopedia only lists her father's first name, not their family name, at least in the version that I have.

Comment: Huh. "Curzon" with a "C"? I'd always imagined it was "Kurzon". Completely irrelevant, and I have no idea why I had a particular spelling in mind...

Comment: Curiously, Curzon is a real family name in the UK, for example the family of Marquis Kurzon of Kedleston.   And for some reason when watching Voyager I half expected they would meet a Kazon sept called the Kazon Dax.